How to relate ADC sampling offset and Local Oscillator offset
Maybe it is a somewhat trivial question, but I have been unsure if my understanding is correct.
I am currently modeling radar signals transmitted and received by two independent stations (bistatic radar). So the local oscillators are independent from each other. One effect I try to model, is a constant frequency offset between the two LOs.
So lets assume I have an LO with nominal frequency $f_0=12MHz$ on both units, and they diverge by +3ppm and -3ppm from the ideal 12MHz.
The radar samples are generated in software and then send out via a DAC on one unit, while being received at the ADC of another unit without any prior mixing (only filter and amplifier).
Setting any radar related processing aside, I understand that such a frequency offset would incurr time shifts from signal to signal (as the local time counters diverge) and also a difference in sample spacing, since the LOs feed the ADCs which also synthesize their sampling frequencies from it.
What I struggle with understanding is how the LO frequency of 12MHz $\pm$ 3ppm relates to a synthesized higher sampling frequency of, lets say, a few GHz.
Is it just scaled by the reciproce of the same factor? E.g. if the sampling frequency is $f_s=1.2GHz$ (so factor 100) and my LO frequency is $f_{LO,1}=12MHz+3ppm$, is it just a factor of 0.01 on the sample spacing and I am done?
Would it be the same for sampling jitter/phase noise?
Any reading suggestions are also very appreciated!
Cheer!
